# Tell function to repeat itself again, after finishing recursion

Tags: haskell, bubble-sort

I'm trying to implement bubblesort in Haskell:

```
bsort:: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
bsort [] = []
bsort [x] = [x]
bsort (x:y:xs)
    | x <= y = x: bsort(y:xs)
    | x >= y = y: bsort(x:xs)
```

after its done it doesn't repeat the whole process again, so the list is not completely sorted. How do I tell the function to repeat itself again, till the whole function is sorted?

For example when I type:
bsort [1,5,2,4]
I get [1,2,4,5]

but when I type:
bsort [9,6,1,5,2,4]
I get [6,1,5,2,4,9], how do I tell to repeat the process with the [6,1,5,2,4,9] again?

Comment: I would have the function you have created as a helper function, and then the actual bubble sort function repeats this until they're all in order. I would use the `until` function for this https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:until

Comment: If I keep my function how it is and use it as a helper function, how would the actual bubble sort function look like?

Comment: If you have an `isSorted :: [a] -> Bool` predicate, it could be as simple as `bubblesort xs = if isSorted xs then xs else bubblesort (bsort xs)`. `bsort` makes *progress* towards sorting the list, while `bubblesort` continues sorting as long as more progress is needed.

Comment: Something like `bsort = until isSorted bsort'`, where `bsort'` is the function you have now. I'll let you implement isSorted as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options you have:

0. Notice that `bubbleSort` does at worst-case *n*<sup>2</sup> swaps, so running `bsort` *n* times will definitely be enough.

   ```
   bubbleSort l = iterate bsort l !! length l
   ```

   This is arguably not BubbleSort. It does to unnecessary work, specifically for an already sorted list, but this is in practice unlikely and it may actually perform *better* on average than the next version, because that does twice as many passes through the list.

   **Exercise** benchmark this version against the ones below.
1. Write a predicate that checks whether the list is sorted.

   ```
   isSorted :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
   ```

   Then you can just iterate `bsort`, check the predicate on the resulting list, if it's `False` rinse&repeat. Actually you might as well begin by checking whether it's sorted, since that means nothing at all needs to be done. As the comments have already explained, this can be done by recursion

   ```
   bubbleSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
   bubbleSort l
    | isSorted l  = l
    | otherwise   = bubbleSort $ bsort l
   ```

   ...or with a standard iteration combinator

   ```
   bubbleSort = until isSorted bsort
   ```

   **Exercise**: implement `isSorted`
2. Notice that the logic in `isSorted` looks a lot like the logic you already have in `bsort`, so seeing as anyway you always call `isSorted` after `bsort` it makes a lot of sense to combine them. Specifically, you let `bsort` return a value telling you whether it performed any swaps:

   ```
   bsort :: Ord a => [a] -> ([a], Bool)
   bsort (x:y:xs)
    | x>y        = (y : fst (bsort $ x:xs), True)
    | otherwise  = let (zs, hasSwapped) = bsort $ y:xs
                   in (x:yz, hasSwapped)
   bsort l = (l, False)
   ```

   **Exercise**: implement `bubbleSort` in terms of this
3. Decide that it's silly to implement `bubbleSort`. Not only is it an unnecessarily quadratic algorithm, it also unnecessary bubbles through the increasing suffix of already-sorted elements at the end of the list (BubbleSort brings the maximum element to the end of the list already in the first pass). And all this boolean checking and iterating is really not idiomatic in Haskell.

   A small change that addresses both of these issues is to switch to the similar *selection sort*, which is essentially just bubble sort bubbling in the other direction and skipping the already sorted elements in the next iteration. That makes it both more efficient, and more idiomatic to write in Haskell:

   ```
   selectionSort :: Ord => [a] -> [a]
   selectionSort l = case extractMin l of
    Just (m, r) -> m : selectionSort r
    Nothing -> []

   extractMin :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe (a, [a])
   ```

   `extractMin =` **exercise**